# How to remove characters from end of a line till a particular character in perl

Tags: perl, string

my string is like

```
$varin="wer.try.iuy.oiu.qert"
```

i wanted to remove characters starting from end of the string till "." is encountered.

expected output:

```
wer.try.iuy.oiu
```

have tried using `chop()`, `substr`  but nothing works .. it removes only last char.

please help :)

Comment: Are you interested in seeing an answer written in Perl6 (a.k.a. Raku)?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are well suited for this kind of problem:

```
$varin =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
```

This matches a dot, followed by several non-dot and then the end of the string. Then removes what was matched.

Another way would be to find the last `.` using `rindex`, then use `substr` to remove the dot and everything after it:

```
my $i = rindex($varin,'.');
$varin = substr($varin,0,$i) if $i>0;
```

Comment: Or `substr($varin, $i) = "" if $i>0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: yes, TMTOWTDI

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  But then again, TANSTAAFL.